# How to read in a file from another Java project

Tags: java, maven

I have two Maven java projects A and B. Project A depends on project B and when from A to call a method from B, project B produces a file and stores it under B's resources/... directory. Then code in project A needs to access the file under B's resource/ directory.

I can't use absolute path to do this. Is there a way to achieve this? I think it should be a common thing to do. Right?

Comment: Have A call a method in B where it returns the path (or file object) of this new produced file?

Comment: Strange,I simply used the relative path in project A and it can reach the file in project B. Amazing. Why? It might be due to the fact that I used the same package structure in the two project (com.test.files)

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2167218/2498729). It may give you more insight. I would add a safe-check to make sure the path exists because executing on it.

Comment: After reading your comment on my answer, I started to wonder. Why would you want project B to create a file within its project structure based on a call from A? My gut is telling me this feels unwise.

Comment: @Robert, let's say you depend on an external library, and you want to call functions in the library from your own library. The result of the function is a file that needs to be stored somewhere. Where to store? That sounds like a very typical situation.

Comment: @user697911 it sounds to me that if A is making the call, A should store the resource. I'm trying to think of a use case, what are you storing? Does the file change? If so do you need to version it, or just overwrite it? If you overwrite it, what happens if it's called twice at once? Does your project have a database? Would this be a better place to store it, so it could be used by multiple projects without any maven dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can get any file from resource directory by following way :

File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("filename").getFile());

And there is another way for doing this, you can keep that file in classpath and to access the classpath from another maven project you can use the following approach :

this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filename");

Answer (score 0):

have same problem solved it by
(verify that your file it in **src/main/resources**)

[image]

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream myFile = classloader.getResourceAsStream("MyFileText.txt");
```

Comment: Great. Where is "resource" to be located?

Comment: in src/main/resources